# No device list in Android DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, ddms

I have the newest eclipse & Android SDK -release 11- installed on Windows Vista. I updated the SDK and chose Android 3.0.1. I connected an Android 3.01 Acer Iconia Tab A500. Installed the original Acer USB driver. The Iconia shows up in Windows and I can connect to the Iconia's file system.
In Eclipse / DDMS no devices are shown in the list.
Kind regards,
Tony Thijs

Comment: What does "adb devices" yield? If it shows a bunch of question marks, your adb server is running with insufficient priviledges.

Comment: * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon

Answer (score 9):

If you are using **Ubuntu**,

Firstly, add your USB vendor ID to the file `51-android.rules`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) for more details.

Next,

```
sudo ./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb start-server
```

Also make sure that your *USB Debugging* is enabled in the device.

Comment: First step is unnecessary for adb.

Comment: The first step is mandatory in Linux since the device drivers don't install automatically.

Comment: This is strange. Oddly enough, on ubuntu 10.10 until now I just plugged in various android devices (amongst them GT5500, LG EVE and Samsung Galaxy Tab) and without prior changes to the udev rules, adb worked fine. Maybe this depends on the distro?

Comment: Can't really say about the distro dependency. I really don't remember which version of Ubuntu I used for my Android programming, but I did need to add the Vendor ID to the above mentioned file, without which, my device was shown as a series of question marks (?????), as your mentioned in one of your comments, in the DDMS and could not be used. Well, I tried simply sudo restarting ADB, without adding the vendor ID, but that alone did not help.

Answer (score 5):

Have you made sure "USB debugging" is enabled on the device?

Settings >> Applications >> Development >> USB debugging

Comment: Yes I did. In the meanwhile I picked up a hint to sync the device using Acer Synch. Initially that worked after a full reboot, but after some 15 minutes the connection was lost again. I suspect power saving options that control the USB port.

Comment: I checked the power settings. Power control on the USB posts is disabled.

Answer (score 5):

If You are using windows manually end process of adb.exe. Pres Ctrl+alt+Del find adb.exe and press "end process".
After that execute 
adb start-server on your command promt.

I did those things and it solved the problem. Hopefully it can also solve your problem.

Comment: This worked for me where everything else was failing!  Thanks indah!

Comment: for me too. First this, then adb kill-server, then adb start-server in a shell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ubuntu 10.10 alongside a500. The instructions from the link and sudo commands helped. I also tried without sudo and that didn't work (got ????? in adb devices). Please note that for my dev I'm using eclipse running under a normal account. Below is my output from "adb devices"

android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
288504640800597 device